# Create a loop function for calculations in with R and save result

Tags: r

I have 20 Stations in 20 files (in txt format like Bariko.txt). I want to do calculations at the same time using a loop in one script, after I save the result in an other file  using the (20) differents stations names (like bariko_result.txt)  in the same directory(20 separated files). 
This is an example:

```
     library(dplyr)
     data=read.csv("~/Task/New_Job/Stations_data/Bariko.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
     data_filtered = filter(data, Month == 2 | Month == 3)
     write.table(data_filtered, file = "bariko_result.txt", quote =FALSE, 
     row.names=FALSE, col.names = TRUE)


        station build   Year Month  
    1   Bariko 24.5  1961     1      
    2   Bariko 29.1  1962     1       
    3   Bariko 26.4  1963     1       
    4   Bariko 29.0  1961     2       
    5   Bariko 22.0  1962     2      
    6   Bariko 25.9  1963     2       
    7   Bariko 24.2  1961     3       
    8   Bariko 23.9  1962     3       
    9   Bariko 24.4  1963     3       
    10  Bariko 24.0  1961     4      
    11  Bariko 24.2  1962     4      
    12  Bariko 24.8  1963     4
```

I can do it for one station but 20 It will take too much time.
Thank you.

Comment: I really don't understand what your setup is. You say you have 50 data frames in text format, but you only show opening one of them. Are each of them in a separate file? Are all those files in one folder, and how are they named? How do you want the output files to be named?

Comment: in a separate file, but the same directory

Comment: But what is it called? Are they named according to a convention? How should the output files be named? You didn't answer any of these.

Comment: I choose to rename all 20 files as 01.txt, 02.txt ,... ,20.txt; and the output like  01_result.txt, 02_result.txt ,..., 20_result.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Input <- paste0(formatC(1:20, width = 2, flag = "0"),".txt")
Output <- paste0(formatC(1:20, width = 2, flag = "0"), "_result.txt")

data <- list()
data_filtered <- list()

for (i in 1:length(Input)){
      data[[i]] <- read.csv(Input[i], header = T, header=T,sep="\t")
      data_filtered[[i]] <- filter(data[[i]], Month == 2 | Month == 3)
      write.table(data_filtered[[i]], file = Output[i], quote =FALSE, 
                  row.names=FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thank very much @LauraS it do exactly what I want. Can I duplicate the loop if I have many calculations to do or just to insert it inside the same loop?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, @NVega, but I can't think of a situation in which you couldn't embed loops within loops. It sometimes gets confusing for a programmer to follow, but R doesn't have any problem with it.